# Does Postfix on Google cloud to forward email need some kind of authentication?

Tags: postfix-mta, mail-server

I am an email server noob.  I own a domain 'mydomain.org' and I'd like to forward emails sent to that domain to other email address, perhaps at 'gmail.com' or 'university.edu'.  I thought I set this up right, but my email log is giving me errors like this:

`connect to mx1.university.edu[171.67.219.71]:25: Connection timed out`

and

`Dec 22 05:17:24 mail-server postfix/smtp[6370]: connect to alt1.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[2607:f8b0:400d:c00::1a]:25: Network is unreachable`

I don't know too much about this, but I imagine there must be some kind of authentication that I need to set up, but I'm shy of the laundry list blog posts.  Does this look like "authentication stuff"?  If so, what do I need to set up next?  If not, any idea why the receiving mail servers drop my server?

Comment: This looks like a network issue. Many internet providers block outbound tcp connections to port 25 and so please check and confirm the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, network issue. For future folks, Google does not allow outgoing connections for SMTP servers, maybe to prevent spam?  Here's info about how to set that up: https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/sending-mail